Why does my code go into an infinite loop?
I have the following code at the moment:
executed = False

while executed == False:
    try:
        inp = input("Enter the variable you want to change (e.g.: limit = 10): ")
        eval(inp, globals())
    except:
        print("Invalid input")
        continue
    print("Variable has been changed")
    executed = True

and I don't quite understand why if I put exit() as an input it goes into an infinite loop outputting the following line over and over again:
Enter the variable you want to change (e.g.: limit = 10): Invalid input
without me further inputting anything.
I am absolutely lost on why it even goes into an infinite loop since I expected it to either completely quit out of it or just print "Invalid input" and then ask me to input something different again.
Why does it keep skipping the input() part and directly jumps to the eval part? (Or at least I assume that's what it's doing).

Cannot repro. exit() causes the process to end for me. Also, I really hope this code is just for experimentation purposes. Code like this should never be used for anything "real".

Well its not exactly "experimentation" but it is a personal project that will not be distributed beyone personal local usage between friends

Now I'm curious. Why would a user ever need to assign variables by name? It sounds like you're abusing the globals dictionary to store data. You probably just want a dictionary that you maintain. This code allows users to break the code in unpredictable ways.

What exactly do you mean by assigning variables by name? My use-case in this case is to have a running "bot" using pure-pythong-adb. I want to be able to pause the script and then give the option to either continue, exit or run this function to change a variable e.g. change a setting in the "bot"

To debug the problem, change the code to following:
from time import sleep

executed = False

while executed is False:
    try:
        inp = input("Enter the variable you want to change (e.g.: limit = 10): \n")
        eval(inp, globals())
    except BaseException as e:
        print("error is:", e, type(e))
        print("Invalid input")
        sleep(2)
        continue
    print("Variable has been changed")
    executed = True

Now the following is happening:

when you enter exit(), eval can correctly execute the command exit().
It throws a SystemExit exception.
BUT, you'll catch it inside your bare except clause(which is equivalent to except BaseException), which means you don't let the script to be finished by that SystemExit exception.
But it seems like it closes the "standard input" file desciprtor.
In the next iteration, when it hits, input(), it cannot read from a closed file(stdin).
From now on, you'll get a ValueError forever.

Update
Yes I checked the source code and it indeed closes the stdin.
Here it adds exit callable to the builtins:
    builtins.exit = _sitebuiltins.Quitter('exit', eof)

and this is what gets called when you say `exit():
class Quitter(object):
    ...
    def __call__(self, code=None):
        # Shells like IDLE catch the SystemExit, but listen when their
        # stdin wrapper is closed.
        try:
            sys.stdin.close()
        except:
            pass
        raise SystemExit(code)


What exactly do you mean by it not being able to read from a closed file(stdin)? My knowledge is rather basic concerning the deeper details concerning python errors inner workings and especially the what the different exceptions mean etc.

Also... is there a way to circumvent this issue so that if exit() is used as an input then it actually exiting the script?

@Westec Every process (including python) has three file descriptors: stdout, stdin, stderr. They are file-like objects from Python's point of view. stdin is where you read input() from. It's usually connected to the terminal(if it's not redirected) which itself connected to your keyboard.

@Westec if you don't want to gracefully shutdown the python process, you can use os._exit(). It basically kills that process. But I definitely do not recommend doing so. You may want to restructure your loop so that you listen for the "string" exit and if it is passed, you return from the function or exit or whatever you want. This is typically done in scripts.

And I think you're aware of why passing user's input to exec and eval is not a good idea.

Ok so the whole issue is, that the exit() command basically disconnects the stdin from the currently running process but not completely exits the python script due to the exception being caught. Because of that the loop starts new and then the input() function itself throws an error which causes it to infinitely loop? Is this a correct understanding of this issue from my side?

@Westec Yes that's correct. I have to dig into the source code to find the part where it closes those file descriptors, but this is all I can tell and it looks like it does so

Yes i am aware of the fact that passing user inputs through exec or eval is generally a bad idea. Since this is for personal use only and will only be shared between friends and exclusively used in a local setting i thought that this is still a bearable solution in this case.

Thank you very much for your help! Very much appreciated. I'll try and figure things out usiing what you told me :D especially just listening for exit seems like a good option to prevent this from happening.

@Westec Yes. right after getting the input and before passing it to eval you can parse the passed string and act accordingly.

I appreciate that you further looked into this and its cool to see how some of this stuff works. I have by now implemented a way that seems to work even though it is far from pretty. Is there a way to gracefully handle this? What im currently doing is checking for "exit" inside of inp and if that is found i do quit() and then I basically check if the "SystemExit" exception is raised in the except block and do quit() once more in there.

@Westec instead of doing that, just don't use bare except clause and the problem is gone. except is equal to except BaseException which will catch every thing. Just use except Exception and you don't need to do those anymore. It simply terminates the program.
